# LINQ ForEach with Replace

Tags: linq

I am trying to replace a string date value "01/01/1700" with an empty string in LINQ.

The date is of type string.

Something like this but I cant get it to work.

```
Query<Client>(sql).ToList().ForEach(x => x.DateOfBirth =
    x.DateOfBirth.Replace("01/01/1700", ""));
```

This code works but its not LINQ.

```
        var result = Query<Client>(sql).ToList();
        foreach (var client in result)
        {
            if (client.DateOfBirth == "01/01/1700")
            {
                client.DateOfBirth = "n/a";
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the data type of `DateOfBirth`?

Comment: I am guessing this is Linq-to-Sql? If so I recommend you check out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx.

Comment: No it a in-house piece of code you can just consider it as a List<Client> Thanks

Comment: first: string is immutable and second: you do not change the value in the list (just a copy of it).

Comment: Is there any way in LINQ to achieve this?

Comment: Not using _proper_ LINQ no.  LINQ is used for _querying_ data, not modifying it.  Your "not LINQ" code is how you should be doing it.

Comment: Undeleted and edited for more clarity. You are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `ToList()`. The result is not visible in the variable you use afterwards.

Try out the following:

```
var list = Query<Client>(sql).ToList();
list.ForEach(l => l.DateOfBirth = l.DateOfBirth.Replace("01/01/1700", "n/a"));
```

Should work fine. Use the `list` variable afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var result = Query<Client>(sql).ToList();
        result.ForEach(l => l.DateOfBirth = l.DateOfBirth.Replace("01/01/1700", "n/a"));
```

Comment: This was posted and removed it works perfectly. If you post it again I will award you the points. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that changes made to an object in a `List` will be reflected in the `Query<Client>` that the object came from.  Apparently this is not the case.  One thing you could try is assigning the list before calling `ForEach()` and using the list from that point on:

```
var clients = Query<Client>(sql).ToList();
clients.ForEach(x => x.DateOfBirth = x.DateOfBirth.Replace("01/01/1700", ""));
```

Also, `ForEach` is not a LINQ operator.  It is a method in the `List` class.  Unlike LINQ operators, it will modify the list that called it and will not return anything.  The way to "modify" data with LINQ is by using `select`:

```
var clients = (from client in Query<Client>(sql).ToList()
               select new Client(client) 
                      { 
                          DateOfBirth = client.DateOfBirth.Replace("01/01/1700", "")
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: That works but only returns a client with a DateOfBirth the rest of its members are missing. I would have to manually set them.

Comment: @ markpcasey You can either create a copy constructor for Client or assign the members in the LINQ query.